# Preferred approach to implement multiple many-to-many relationships?

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I am building a database that includes the following tables:

- `pages`
- `users`

A particular user can access (or is associated with) a page with one of the following roles (permissions):

- Owner
- Administrator
- Editor

What will be the best approach in this kind of situation? Either to setup join tables like this:

- `owners` (`page_id`, `user_id`)
- `administrators` (`page_id`, `user_id`)
- `editors` (`page_id`, `user_id`)

Or using a single join table:

- `pages_users` (`page_id`, `user_id`, `role`)

Also, if the second approach is preferable, should `role` attribute be a `string` (such as `'owner'`, `'administrator'`, or `'editor'`) or something like `role_id` and the roles defined in a separate table as follows:

- `roles` (`id`, `name`)

If there's a completely different approach which fits the need in a more appropriate manner, please let me know.

Also, is there any special name for this type of relationship(s) in database jargon? I am unable to craft the question's title right, edits are welcome.

Thank you for your answers

Comment: Do you have a "super" user - one who can edit/admin everything?  Is a page owned by a singler 'user'?  Etc.  I don't yet see the full model that you want.

Comment: There could be multiple super users. A page could be owned by multiple users (owners) as like multiple administrators and editors.

Answer (score 1):

Since the primary key (page_id, user_id) is same for all roles it would be better to put all roles in a single table, the one you named pages_users.

The question on using role_id and a separate roles table is a matter of personal preference. I would use a separate table, at least if I'm going to populate an UI component list based on the choices.

Answer (score 0):

If there will be no additions to the type of roles, go with option 1. If you expect to add other roles later, go with 2. And indeed make a FK referencing a table Roles (and my preference would be just by name, not id, saves a join). Remember that you have to build a user interface for maintaining roles in option 2, and give someone permission to use that.